# CSS 3D transform container to reverse the 3D transform of the child

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

In the following HTML

```
<article>
    <div></div>
</article>
```

the `div` is absolutely positioned in an arbitrary position inside the `article` and transformed with an arbitrary matrix3d.

How to "reverse" the transform of the `div` by transforming the `article`, so that the `div` appears rectangular again in its original size?

Here's how the situation looks: http://jsfiddle.net/kBWcc/

Note: Usage of matrix3d in this case is obligatory.

Comment: I don't understand `matrix3d()` well enough off the top of my head, but you need to apply an "inverted" version of the same thing to the `article`.

Comment: the blue div is now floating on top of the red div, i think this is your problem?

Comment: what i want to achieve is that the blue figure will look as if it didn't have any 3d transformation (rectangular), but not by transforming the blue `div`, but the red `article`. in other words - distort the red object so that the blue object appears rectangular, in its original dimensions.

Comment: @KeesSonnema please look at the example in Safari or Chrome. i used only the -webkit- CSS prefix.

Comment: @thirtydot — yes, that is the question: how that "inverted" version would look

Comment: I removed my previous comment. There's no need to do the maths manually when `WebKitCSSMatrix` already does it. I had no idea that existed.

Comment: @thirtydot yep, `WebKitCSSMatrix` does all the magic, and in fact is is the "inverted" matrix that works here, as you suggested. The trick is only to place both objects over the same point of transformation origin to achieve the effect. Then one can "translate" them apart again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After half a day of trying i finally found a so-far webkit-only solution, which involves WebKitCSSMatrix object.

Here's how a solution looks: http://jsfiddle.net/kBWcc/2/

```
var t = window.getComputedStyle($('div').get(0)).webkitTransform;
  , m = new WebKitCSSMatrix(t);

$('article').css('-webkit-transform', m.inverse());
$('div').css('-webkit-transform', m.translate(100, 100));​
```

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle to display the matrix3d output in the div inner text: http://jsfiddle.net/brcaswell/kBWcc/8/

I wanted to avoid JS, but this solution is pretty good.. good find